# How to open SDF file

Tags: database, database-schema, file-format, legacy

So I am aware that typically an SDF file would be thought to be a SQL Server Compact Database file.  However it is highly unlikely that is the case here.

I have a client that is trying to pull their data out of a legacy system.  I've been given access to the data files and some go back as far as 1998. According to this:

http://fileinfo.com/extension/sdf

these files are likely Standard Data Files.  This makes sense based on the naming of the files as well. Each file name appears to be what I would normally consider a table name. My understanding is that a SQL Server Compact Database would have all of these tables in a single file.

So the question now is what system can read these SDF files.  What late 90s database programs would use SDF files?  I've tried Googling this and it doesn't look like there is much on the topic.

Comment: Did you look at the file content? Is it binary or readable?

Comment: @ErikEJ  The files appear to be ASCII encoded when I look at the data but it is mostly NUL characters.  The only parts that have data are not readable at all.

Comment: You could use my SQL Compact Toolbox - it has a file type detection feature for all SQL Server Compact database file versions

Comment: @ErikEJ The first thing I used :) I didn't realize you were the creator though, thanks for reaching out. Again, I really don't think this is SQL Server Compact.  Based on how old the files are and the fact that the executing code appears to be BASIC-like I think this is a PICK-like multi-value database system.  It's just very hard to find clear information on it and it appears that these systems did not adhere to many standards that I can replicate today without knowing exactly what made this data.